# byte to string android

Tags: android, string, byte

So I'm using files to save some scores of my program but the problem is that I don't can't just print them. I tryed several things but I don't find the right one the is my code:

```
try{
        String FILENAME = "FrogScoreFile";
        FileInputStream fos = openFileInput(FILENAME);
        byte[] b = new byte[1];
        fos.read(b);
        fos.close();
        String score= String b;
        game5HighScore.setText(b);
        }catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: The way youre doing is wrong..change this `String score= String b;` to `String score= new String (b);`  and btw, you'll need `game5HighScore.setText(score);` and not `game5HighScore.setText(b);`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can convert `Byte array` to string by creating `new string` object.

```
byte[] b = new byte[1];
fos.read(b);
fos.close();
String message = new String(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
        String FILENAME = "FrogScoreFile";
        FileInputStream fos = openFileInput(FILENAME);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fos));
        String yourText = br.readLine();
        br.close();
        game5HighScore.setText(yourText);
    }catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
}
```

By The way. why not save your score with SharedPreferences Or SQLite database?

[SharedPrefrences Guide.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#)

```
public static void saveScore(Context context) {
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(
            "settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putInt("score", 100);
    editor.commit();
}

public static int readScore(Context context) {
    final SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences("settings",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sp.getInt("score", 0);
}
```

Comment: I don't really get the sharedpreferences, cause I don't find A good guide

Comment: The one from google I already readed it but I did'nt quit get it. I need A good example to see it